# Regarding binding MySql and Apache to localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

I've been reading articles on securing MySql and Apache on Ubuntu, and one of the suggestions was 'Make sure MySQL only allows connections from localhost.'

This means doing `[bind-address = 127.0.0.1]`

Thing is, do I leave it bound to localhost even when the site goes live?

The site interacts with the DB to fetch and add data. Will other users be able to use the site when they access the site using my domain name? I'm a little confused with this. How is this done?

When it goes live what am I supposed to change it to, so it still remains safe and not vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as MySQL is running on the web server host, you should keep `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.  When a user calls your site, the web server, not the user, calls MySQL to run a query.  So the query comes from the web server's IP address, which is 127.0.0.1 if it's colocated with MySQL.  So in order for your site to operate, you only need to be able to accept connections from localhost.  On the other hand, if you allow connections from anywhere, then anyone on the net could connect to your MySQL server, if your firewall allowed it (maybe by misconfiguration).

Another option is to have a DMZ between internal and external firewalls, with the web server in the DMZ, and MySQL on a separate host behind the internal firewall.  The internal firewall only allows connections to MySQL from the web server host.  This puts an additional firewall layer between the outside and your MySQL server.  Then you'd need to set `bind-address` to allow connections from the web server.